# SPIRV-Reflect evaluates BDA size as 16 bytes instead of 8

Tags: reflection, glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I ran into a problem when SPIRV-Reflect from LunarG's Vulkan SDK (v1.3.275.0) evaluates push constant size with a single BDA as 16 bytes instead of expected 8.

I think that BDA size has to be 8 bytes wide since it is a pointer.

Providing shader and reflection code:

**Shader code**

```
layout(buffer_reference, scalar, buffer_reference_align = 4) readonly buffer CameraData {
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 view_proj;
    vec3 position;
};

layout(push_constant) uniform PushContants {
    CameraData camera;
} pc;
```

**Reflection code**

```
uint32 push_constant_range_count = 0;
spvReflectEnumeratePushConstantBlocks(&reflect_module, &push_constant_range_count, nullptr);

std::vector<SpvReflectBlockVariable*> reflect_push_constant_ranges(push_constant_range_count);
spvReflectEnumeratePushConstantBlocks(&reflect_module, &push_constant_range_count, reflect_push_constant_ranges.data());

for (auto& reflect_range : reflect_push_constant_ranges) {
    push_constant_range.size += reflect_range->size;
    push_constant_range.offset = 0;
    push_constant_range.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_ALL;
}
```

I *know* that I have slightly incorrect code "**Reflection code**" section, which may lead to errors when using two push-constant ranges in different shader stages. However, I have written it just for test and I only use a single push-constant range in vertex stage which was defined in code I provided.

I also provide some debug information from reflected push-constant range:
[image: Push constant reflection data]

And here is description of `camera` member in `PushConstants` struct:
[image: description of camera member in PushConstants struct]

On images above it is clearly visible that for some reason PushConstants size is 16 bytes instead of expected 8. What is the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Would make more sense to ask this on the Khronos bug tracker?

Comment: @solidpixel actually, I don't know if it is my error or bug in SPIRV-Reflect itself